# Synaptic TouchPad Not working in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10, synaptic

Synaptic touchpad is not working in Dell 5547. I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 and mouse pad stopped working. It used to work in Windows.

Since i am new to Ubuntu i don't know much to sort it myself. I would really appreciate your help.